# How to requestPlayersProfile with node-globaloffensive

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working a few hours with this and I have absolute no idea what I have to do, never did anything with node.js or even javascript.

Thats my code so far:

```
const SteamUser = require('steam-user');
const SteamTotp = require('steam-totp');
const GlobalOffensive = require('globaloffensive');
const config = require('./config');

let user = new SteamUser();
let csgo = new GlobalOffensive(user);

csgo.on('debug', console.log);
user.on('error', console.error);

const logInOptions = {
  accountName: config.accountName,
  password: config.password
}

user.logOn(logInOptions);

user.on('loggedOn', res => {
  console.log("Logged into Steam as " + user.steamID.getSteam3RenderedID());

  user.setPersona(SteamUser.EPersonaState.Online);
  user.gamesPlayed(730);

  csgo.on('connectionStatus', console.log);
    csgo.on('connectedToGC', () => {
        console.log('Connected to GC!');

    csgo.on('getaccountData', () => {
      console.log('Got account data!');

    });
  });
});
```

So as I understood I need the accountData to get the informations I want requestPlayersProfile(steamid[, callback])
But how do I get the accountData? Just tried it the "same" way I did with the game coordinator.

https://github.com/DoctorMcKay/node-globaloffensive

Comment: Can you: console.log('Got account data!'); console.log(user); ?

Comment: @LajosArpad I can console.log(user); I'm getting tons of information about my botaccount there. But only if its befor the csgo.on('getaccountData'...});

Comment: I mean inside getaccountdata. I do not know much about your problem, but I have much experience with Javascript. Trying to help.

Comment: Yeah, getaccountdata isn't working (guess thats just my fault thought this could be right tbh :D), I added the repository to the question. Also found this in the handles.js 
handlers[Language.MatchmakingGC2ClientHello] = function(body) { let proto = decodeProto(Protos.CMsgGCCStrike15_v2_MatchmakingGC2ClientHello, body); this.emit('accountData', proto); this.accountData = proto; }

Comment: @LajosArpad it is working now with: if ( csgo.haveGCSession ) {


        

        var account_id = new SteamID("76561197971695147");
        csgo.requestPlayersProfile(account_id, function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
    //}, 3000);
});

csgo.on("playersProfile", function(data) {
    console.log("Profile gotten");
});
 I actually have no Idead what I did there, just found something and copied it.